# Can we restrict orientation of mobile app in maximo anywhere

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I want only landscape orientation to be enabled in **maximo anywhere** app and disable portrait mode. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Since all the Maximo Anywhere apps are using Cordova/PhoneGap under the covers, you can follow this approach.

http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/config_xml_prevent_screen_rotation